# Raise an exception on assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, binding, variable-binding

Is there any way to prevent a name from being bound, or a variable from being rebound?
For instance, given a `foo` variable, is it possible to have an assignment operation raise an exception?

More concretely, provided we have a total control on `foo`'s class, is the following session possible?

```
>>> foo = 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
WhateverError: foo cannot be bound
```

I know that it's possible to make class attributes read-only, or to use `__slots__` to prevent from adding new members, but I want to know if the same could be achieved on free variables (as in, non-member variables).
Besides, I assume that the left member of the assignment is a valid identifier.

*I'm asking this question out of curiosity. There's nothing I'm trying to accomplish with this, so this is not an XY problem.*